# how to edit the SiteTemplate which is used to create a subsite

Tags: site-template, site

Initially i 'm having a site-template which contains a list View web part and  is used to create the sub-site . i need modify the web part attached to the template.so how can i edit the template to overcome those requirements.

Comment: FYI Be carefull with site templates. Some features don't work well together with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to edit a site template (wsp), all of which involve:

1. changing the extension do .zip
2. extract the contents
3. make your changes
4. recompile the zip
5. set extension back to wsp

In-depth details here:

http://sharepointroot.com/2010/07/07/editing-contents-of-a-wsp-sharepoint/